# Google sometimes hides my site, and sometimes shows it

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, google-index

I'm running a blog and it seems that Google isn't placing it in the search results properly. For example, one of my posts is called "changing Exposure in gimp".

I searched that exact phrase in Google and my page was not listed in the results, even though I know it's indexed. I'll explain why later.

Here's a screenshot of Google with the search.

[image]

Now, if I search `"changing Exposure in gimp" digitally free` (the name of my blog) I get the following:

[image]

My blog is now the first result on the page. The strange thing I'm wondering about is **why Google ommited my site** when I simply searched for `changing exposure in gimp`. Because of the second result, I know that my site is indexed (and Webmaster Tools says that it's indexed as well). Google sometimes decides to show my site and sometimes it doesn't.

Why is that? In the Blogger settings, I have set it so that search engines can index and view my blog. If you're interested, my robots.txt says the following:

```
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: 

User-agent: *
Disallow: /search
Allow: /

Sitemap: http://example.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=UPDATED
```

Why would Google do this to me? Is there a hidden setting or something that I don't know about?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but your sitemap listing is incorrect. You have listed your feed there, not a sitemap.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Your site is indexed.  Google has no obligation to show it on the first page (or first 100 pages) of results.  If you repeat the first search and start looking through the pages of search results, it will show up there or after you click "repeat this search showing omitted results."

Basically, your site is not ranking well.  It's there though.

Comment: Yep. The reason why they see themselves in the second set of results is by putting the site name in the query they are essentially forcing their way to the top.

Comment: Yep.  The long tail strikes again.

Comment: @JCL1178 Hmm... I found out my answer myself, as the site was in the [Google Supplementary Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplemental_Result), a place where sites Google doesn't believe to be worthy for the main index reside. A page there only appears when "there are not enough pages in the main index that are returned within the search" (Wikipedia).

Comment: @d.free Same as what I mentioned in my answer. The "repeat this search showing omitted results" option is the supplementary index. The larger point remains unchanged...your site is not ranking well and that's why it isn't coming up.

Comment: @JCL1178 I already pressed the "repeat this search showing ommitted results" button. Only those 4 pages (not mine) showed up.